# Peaceful music in episode 7 and 54 of Naruto

Tags: naruto, music

In episode 7 of *Naruto*, there's a peaceful flute-like music when team 7 entered the land of waves ([YouTube reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khbE3tVl_n0&t=92s))

A shorter version also plays towards the beginning of episode 54, right before Temari and Shikamaru battle in the chuunin exams ([YouTube reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Owt6LiM40nk&t=31s))

What's that song?

Answer (score 0):

That would be [Naruto OST 1 - Evening](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qv7btgqaAGc) (夕暮れ, Yūgure) as composed by [Toshio Masuda](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=fr&sp=nmt4&u=https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toshio_Masuda_(compositeur)&xid=17259,15700022,15700124,15700149,15700168,15700173,15700186,15700189,15700190,15700201,15700205&usg=ALkJrhjasJ0aZS8UiOdw6PSTRzYe3DtAsg)